# How do I assign an address to a label? WinMIPS64

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mips64

Everything runs well until I reach lw r9, 0(r7) because I dont have the address of the labels. How do I make it so I can store the address of the labels and jump to the label?

Im supposed to make it work in WinMIPS64

```
//C code
switch (k){
          case 0: f = i + j; break ; /* k = 0*/
          case 1: f = g + h; break ; /* k = 1*/
          case 2: f = g - h; break ; /* k = 2*/
          case 3: f = i - j; break ; /* k = 3*/
          }
```

"Theoretical" MIPS Code(not actual MIPS)

```
    slt $t3, $s5, $zero   # $t3=1 if k < 0
    bne $t3, $zero , Exit # if k < 0 go to Done
    slt $t3, $s5, $t2     # Test if k < 4
    beq $t3, $zero , Exit # if k >= 4 go to Done

    add $t1, $s5, $s5
    add $t1, $t1, $t1

    #Assume Four sequential words in memory with the address in $t4 contain the 
    #addresses corresponding to the Labels L0,L1....

    add $t1, $t1, $t4 # $t1=address of JumpTable[k]
    lw $t0, 0($t1)     # $t1=JumpTable[k]

    jr $t0

    L0: add $s0, $s3, $s4  # f = i + j
       j Done
    L1: add $s0, $s1, $s2  # f = g + h
       j Done
    L2: sub $s0, $s3, $s4  # f = g - h
       j Done
    L3: sub $s0, $s1, $s2  # f = i - j
    Done:
```

What I have Using WinMips64

```
;r0 = $zero
;r1 = f s0
;r2 = h s2
;r3 = i s3
;r4 = j s4
;r5 = k s5
;r10 = g s1
;r6 = Temp1
;r7 = Temp2
;r8 = Temp3
;r9 = Temp4

    .data
f:      .word 0,0
h:  .word 0x00000010
i:  .word 0x00000000
j:  .word 0x00000000
k:  .word 0x00000010
Temp1:  .word 0x00000000
Temp2:  .word 0x00000000
Temp3:  .word 0x00000000
Temp4:  .word 0x00101000
g:      .word 0x00001000

    .text
start: jal SwitchCases   ; call subroutine
       nop
       halt

SwitchCases: 
         lw r1, f(r0)
         lw r2, h(r0)
         lw r3, i(r0)
         lw r4, j(r0)
         lw r5, k(r0)
         lw r6, Temp1(r0)
         lw r7, Temp2(r0)
         lw r8, Temp3(r0)
         lw r9, Temp4(r0)
         lw r10, g(r0)
         slt r6, r5, r0
         bne r6, r0, Exit
             slt r6, r5, r7
             beq r6, r0, Exit
             dadd r7, r5, r5
             dadd r7, r7, r7
         
         dadd r7, r7, r8
         lw r9, 0(r7)
         
             jr r9
             
L0:          dadd r1, r3, r4
             j Exit  
L1:          dadd r1, r10, r2
             j Exit
L2:          dsub r1, r3, r4
             j Exit
L3:          dsub r1, r10, r2
             j Exit
Exit:
```

As the previous code stated $t1 must store the address of JumpTable[k].

Comment: Put the labels into the jump table, e.g. `.word L0`.

Comment: Like so?

.word L0, L1, L2, L3

Comment: Yes that should work as well.

Comment: Thx, but which register should I store those addresses?

Comment: Any temporary register you want to load into to use with `jr`.  MIPS has plenty, pick one the rest of your code isn't using, or doesn't need preserved during that portion.